# Correct security implementation strategy for multi-provider authentication and api route protection with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, fastify

We have a small React Web application with a Fastify backend (but can very easily apply the same concepts to Express js) that feeds the db data to the frontend clients.
Some of the API routes are protected by means of middleware checking the validity of the access token.
Our auth strategy used to be only credentials based, ie using Username and Password.
We have recently implemented authentication by Google and Facebook as well and for the most part, they seem to work well.

We now want to replicate our web application to a mobile application.

I have never written a mobile app and am currently busy learning React-Native.
I managed to implement Google Auth on the IOS app.

Here is the problem.   I am not sure how to implement token validation for mobile clients on protected routes using the Google access token.  I am however able to successfully implement validation if I use the id token.
My understanding is that validation on protected routes should be done using the access token, otherwise, what is the point of the access token in the first place.
Anyway, my understanding of the entire authentication flow is clearly flawed.

I just need some advice, samples or references to articles that I can read that can clarify the concepts to me.

**Just the summary of what I hope to achieve:**

- a single backend with various (but not all) protected routes
- the backend to support credential-based, Google and Facebook authentication strategies
- backend middleware to check the validity of the access token
- backend should serve both native mobile and web applications.

Sample of a protected route:

```js
fastify.get(
    "/protectedroute",  
    { preValidation: [fastify.googleverify] },  //<--- Middleware only checking Google validity currently.  TODO: Multi-provider middleware to be created
    async (request, reply) => {
      reply.code(200).send({ message: "authenticated", user: request.user });
    }
  );
```

Sample of middleware to check google `id_token` validity:

```js
fastify.decorate("googleverify", async function (request, reply, done) {
    if (!request.raw.headers.authorization) {
      return done(new Error("Missing token header"));
    }
    const bearer = request.raw.headers.authorization;
    const token = bearer.split(" ");
    try {
      const userinfo = await verify(token[1]);
      request.user = userinfo;
      return done();
    } catch (error) {
      reply.code(401).send({ message: "Not Authorized", error: error });
    }
  });
```